# Usage of 'directed to'

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to state that a text is 'directed to' children, or would a different choice of words be preferable?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Edwin.  Because any text of articulation at a higher percentage ranking is going to be directed towards the children because someone of a lower ranking fears being overruled by a higher grouping of individuals.

Comment: Hi Kaylee, welcome to EL&U. This reads more like a comment than an answer. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. a dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about ...meant for.... as an option, though I vote for ...aimed at...' as the first option.

I recall having read some government communications that read like, "I am directed to inform you...., or I have been directed to inform you...."